# Amazon s3 bucket ListObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload my static images on amazon s3 bucket through vb.net sdk using PutBucketRequest. and it is creates required bucket. but when i am listing out object using ListObjectsRequest(), it gives me following errors.

1. A first chance exception of type 'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception' occurred in AWSSDK.dll   ( in my visual studio editor's immediate window)
2. Maximum number of retry attempts reached : 3 ( in exception block)

My code is looking as follows :

```
Dim s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("xxxx", "xxxx", regionEndpoint.APSoutheast1) 

client.PutBucket(New PutBucketRequest().WithBucketName(BucketName).WithBucketRegion(S3Region.APS1))

Dim listObjectsRequest As ListObjectsRequest = New   ListObjectsRequest().WithBucketName(BucketName).WithPrefix(FolderName).WithDelimiter("/")
listObjectsRequest.MaxKeys = 1
listObjectsRequest.Timeout = 400
objects = client.ListObjects(listObjectsRequest) //Here i got error.
```

I have seen many example, but I can not find any solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the bucket region on the ListObjectsRequest ?

Comment: yes. and I have solved this using AmazonS3Config CommunicationProtocol to Protocol.HTTP

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using AmazonS3Config CommunicationProtocol to Protocol.HTTP

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the timeout value. Timeout is in milliseconds.  Did you mean to use 400 (4/10ths of a second)?  That is pretty fast, so probably timing out.